# compass radial gradient looks wrong in IE & firefox

Tags: css, compass-sass

I'm trying to create a radial gradient using compass and it renders fine in chrome but when I view it in firefox or IE the gradient squishes back down to a circle instead of elongated ellipse.

This is what I tried.

```
  @mixin radial-shadow-horizontal-rule(){
     height: 5px;
     @include background-image(radial-gradient(50% 0%, 50% -5px, rgba(150,150,150,0.4) 0%, white 100%));
  }

  .radial-gradient{
     @include  radial-shadow-horizontal-rule();
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="radial-gradient"></div>
```

Any help would be darn lovely.

Comment: Please post your html.  Even better make a jsfiddle of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I would use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to create your radial gradient because this usually works in all browsers.